# Deduct % from outputted number and display a new number

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

How can I deduct a certain percentage from the outputted number and display a newly calculated number?

This is what I mean:

Original number is outputted by

```
<?= $number['originalnumber'] ?>
```

which on a user's display shows up as, let's say, number 199.

I want to deduct 3% from number 199, which results in 193.03 and display this new value instead of 199.

Basically calculating on the fly and outputting a new value, so the user never sees number 199 but only a new number 193.03

Mathematic formula is 199 - 199 * .03 = 193.03

So it would be something like this probably

```
<?= $number['originalnumber'] ?> - ( <?= $number['originalnumber'] ?> * 0.3 ) = display new value on user's screen.
```

I'm not exactly a programmer and have no idea how to do it, so the good line of code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
199 - 199 * .03 = 193.03
```

is

```
199 * 0.97 = 193.03
```

So

```
<?= $number['originalnumber'] * .97 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to just multiply it by .97.

`<?php echo ($number['originalnumber'] * .97) ?>`

You'll probably want to format the number using the function `printf()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The basics of this are pretty easy as already shown.

```
<?= $number['originalnumber'] ?> - ( <?= $number['originalnumber'] ?> * 0.03 ) = <?= $number['originalnumber']*0.97 ?>
```

Since it's for display it's probably a good idea to format the number as well so you don't end up with a silly number of decimal places. There are a bunch of options here, but the most logical is probably [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
<?= $number['originalnumber'] ?> - ( <?= $number['originalnumber'] ?> * 0.03 ) = <?= number_format($number['originalnumber']*0.97,2) ?>
```

Comment: Watch out because 0.3 (30%) is not the same as 0.03 (3%).

Comment: Good point. I just copied and pasted that from the question. I guess I should have proof read as well.